# Why doesn't the next screen show up in kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I am expecting the following kivy app to switch screens when I press and then release the button, but nothing happens and there's no error on the terminal. When I run the app, the GirisEkrani screen show up, and then when I press and release the button in GirisEkrani, the next screen (GirisEkrani2) should show up. Do you how to make that work?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<ekranApp>
    GirisEkrani:
        id: ge
        Button:
            text: "İleri"
            on_release: ge.manager.current = ge.manager.next()

    GirisEkrani2:
        Button:
            id: ge2
            text: "Ileri 2"
            on_release: ge2.manager.current = ge2.manager.next()

    KontrolEkrani:
        id: ke
        Button:
            text: "Geri"
            on_release: ke.manager.current = ke.manager.previous()
""")
class GirisEkrani(Screen):
    pass

class GirisEkrani2(Screen):
    pass

class KontrolEkrani(Screen):
    pass

class ekranApp(App, ScreenManager):
    def build(self):
        #root = ScreenManager()
        #root.add_widget(GirisEkrani(name = "giris_ekrani"))        
        #root.add_widget(GirisEkrani2(name = "giris_ekrani2"))
        #root.add_widget(KontrolEkrani(name = "kontrol_ekrani"))
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ekranApp().run()
```

While people seem to advocate the use of .kv files as opposed to using pure Python, I find it very frustrating to have no errors showing up when something doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build()` method of an `App` is expected to return a `Widget` which will be the root of the `Widget` tree for your `App`, but yours returns the `App` itself. I suspect that will cause problems. However, your code is not working because you are not setting the names of the `Screens`. Here is a corrected version of your `kv`:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<ekranApp>:
    GirisEkrani:
        id: ge
        name: "giris_ekrani"
        Button:
            text: "İleri"
            on_release: ge.manager.current = ge.manager.next()

    GirisEkrani2:
        id: ge2
        name: "giris_ekrani2"
        Button:
            text: "Ileri 2"
            on_release: ge2.manager.current = ge2.manager.next()

    KontrolEkrani:
        id: ke
        name: "kontrol_ekrani"
        Button:
            text: "Geri"
            on_release: ke.manager.current = ke.manager.previous()
""")
```

Also, your `id` for `GirisEkrani2` is actually set on the `Button`.

Comment: That worked, but can you please explain how does adding names fix the problem? I don't even see those names used anywhere in the code.

Comment: I can only echo the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage): `When you are creating a screen, you absolutely need to give a name to it` (this is shown in bold).